# How to correctly send a patch request in frontend and backend in node environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, httprequest, fetch-api

I am trying to update a resource using patch method. I am completely unable to do so. I am using only Node.js and no React.

My MongoDB schema:
[image: My MongoDB schema]

I have to update the `desc` field. My back-end patch request is working. The code for patch request is:
[image: My patch request at back-end]

At Postman, it is working fine:

[image: Postman patch request]

You can see the record in the DB is updated:

[image: MongoDB record updated]

I need to update it through a form having a text area.

[image: My front-end form]

I have attached a function in my front-end JavaScript to the submit button for creating a fetch request.

[image: My front-end JavaScript code]

Below is my form in HTML.

[image: My HTML form]

Here is how the button is linked with the function:

[image: link between the form submit button and fetch function]

This is the error I am getting:

[image: The error]

Here is my front-end console:

[image: console]

My fetch request for patch JavaScript codes:

```
await fetch(window.location.href, {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          },
        credentials: 'include',  
        body: JSON.stringify({
          desc: abc,
        })
        
      })
        .then((response) =>  {
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        })
  };
```

Comment: Hi Gyanendra, good detail on the question but can you include the code/errors/details info copy/pasted strings rather than images.

Comment: Hello @Matt, I stopped the form from being submitted. I modified my code to `onclick="event.preventDefault(); patched();"` i my html form. I used this JavaScript code. I am getting an Ok response. But while I log my data on console at back end. I received a data like this `{ '{"desc":"test"}': '' }`. I have used the same JavaScript code as specified above. I don't think it's the way I should be receiving data.  I need to change it to update record for my mongo dB

Comment: I have my JavaScript code their

Comment: I have solved the problems. I recommend following the article and CodePen link.
Article Link 
[https://gomakethings.com/how-to-send-data-to-an-api-with-the-vanilla-js-fetch-method/]
CodePen
[https://codepen.io/cferdinandi/pen/xxGaWQY?editors=1112]